# Lucene Search Issue with one to many relationships in Groovy

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, lucene

I am facing issue in search of one to many relationship using Lucene query. E.g. we have a class member which contains many jobs. In member domain class we have

```
//Member Domain Class
static searchable = {
        analyzer "default"
        only = ['memberName']
        job component: true
    }
```

In job domain class we have

```
//Job Domain Class
static searchable = {
        analyzer "default"
        only = ['title','experience']
    }
```

Now lets say we have following data in Job

[image]

So Member 1 has experience of 2 years as ‘Manager’ and 4 years as ‘Director’.

Now If I want to search a member with ‘Manager’ title who has 4 or more years of experience then my query is

```
query = “ title:( Manager)  AND  experience:[4 TO *]  ”
searchResults = Member.search(query, params){
}
```

I don’t have any such member so it should not return me any member, but it’s returning me Member 1 because it’s matching title ‘Manager’ and 4 year of experience of ‘Director’ title.

How can I filter out this record?

Comment: If it's an exact match that you need shouldn't you be running a regular createCriteria? If you have indexes created then you are all set even for couple of hundreds of thousand results!

Comment: You mean should i use Hibernate createcriteria? But I am using Lucene for all searches.

Comment: You certainly can use Lucene search but createCriteria will solve the problem easily and will do the job.

Comment: @Sap, can you give some me some sample code, how to do that. I am using searchable grails plugin. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intead of searching through member and looking for jobs now we are searching for jobs and looking for there member.

```
def searchResults = Job.search(query,param)
```

May be it helps.